# PhoneGap Build icon is showing on my device

Tags: android, cordova, icons, phonegap-build, dpi

I am developing a simple app, but cannot get my icon to appear on the device. Instead, I am getting the default Cordova icon.

Here is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" versionCode="1" version="1.0.1">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>Test</description>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.5.0"/>
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false"/>
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default"/>
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="21"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle"/>
    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" platform="android" qualifier="xxhdpi" />
    </platform>
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    </platform>
</widget>
```

My two icons reside in the res/icon/android/ folder which is at the root of my project.

Note that the icon DOES appear on the online PhoneGap Build online site, but not on the device.

When I add the following to the config.xml file, I DO get the icon on my device:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

However, I am not sure which of the icons I should be using at the top-level of my project. There are various icons, depending on the device's screen DPI. Which one should I pick?

Is this the correct to go?
Different devices have different screen DPIs, so I would assume I would need to supply the correct icon for each device screen configuration.

Thank you,
Nir

Answer (score 0):

You must read the docs.

You say **when** you add

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
```

you do get the icon.

There is no when, this is a must. This is the default icon and you must put this in. Please read the docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/#icons

At the moment you are not following the docs instructions. If you plan to deploy to app stores you must do this or your app will either be rejected or won't work on all devices.

"Different devices have different screen DPIs, so I would assume I would need to supply the correct icon for each device screen configuration."

This is covered in the docs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I did read the docs, and I have to say that they are not clear as it doesn't say that the <icon src="icon.png" /> tag is a MUST.
It just says:

The simplest icon configuration is a single default icon.png:
  <icon src="icon.png" />
The default icon must be named icon.png and must reside in the root of your application folder. If no other icon configurations are specified, each platform will attempt to use this file as the default icon.

I understood that IF you supply it, then it must follow the configuration specified in the doc. Obviously I was wrong...